# await vs .Result with HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync

Tags: json, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpcontent

I have a custom model binder:

```
public class JsonPolyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var content = actionContext.Request.Content;
        var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, bindingContext.ModelType, settings);
        bindingContext.Model = obj;
        return true;
    }
}
```

With large payload, content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result seems to timeout my web requests.

The model binder interface forces synchronous API's...but by moving this code into my controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoStuff()
{
    var json = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     ......
}
```

And consuming using await over .Result - the web requests go through without a problem. I am curious as to why?

Comment: Result blocks until the task had completed. Do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Result in Task it would block the current executing thread until it returns the result.

If you `await` the call, the request runs asynchronously without blocking the thread and you can run multiple request (tasks) functions using `await` without blocking the thread.

So it is better to use await than result.